# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm trying to create a simple program that tells you your lucky number according to numerology. I keep on getting this error:

```
File "number.py", line 12, in <module>
    sumln = (int(sumall[0])+int(sumall[1]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

My script is:

```
birthday = raw_input("When is your birthday(mm/dd/yyyy)? ")
summ = (int(birthday[0])+int(birthday[1]))
sumd = (int(birthday[3])+int(birthday[4]))
sumy= (int(birthday[6])+int(birthday[7])+int(birthday[8])+int(birthday[9]))
sumall = summ + sumd + sumy
print "The sum of your numbers is", sumall
sumln = (int(sumall[0])+int(sumall[1]))
print "Your lucky number is", sumln`
```

Comment: The value stored in `sumall` is an integer (the result of the sum of 3 other integers).  Yet a couple lines down, you attempt to subscript that integer hence the error. (!)

Comment: You may also want to use `birthday.split('/')` to separate day, month and year.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to sum the digit of a number, one way to do it is using [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) + a generator expression:

```
sum(int(i) for i in str(155))
```

I modified a little your code using `sum()`, maybe you want to take a look at it:

```
birthday = raw_input("When is your birthday(mm/dd/yyyy)? ")
summ = sum(int(i) for i in birthday[0:2])
sumd = sum(int(i) for i in birthday[3:5])
sumy = sum(int(i) for i in birthday[6:10])
sumall = summ + sumd + sumy
print "The sum of your numbers is", sumall
sumln = sum(int(c) for c in str(sumall)))
print "Your lucky number is", sumln
```

Answer (score 30):

The error is exactly what it says it is; you're trying to take `sumall[0]` when `sumall` is an int and that doesn't make any sense.  What do you believe `sumall` should be?

Answer (score 8):

Just to be clear, all the answers so far are correct, but the reasoning behind them is not explained very well.

The `sumall` variable is not yet a string. Parentheticals will not convert to a string (e.g. `summ = (int(birthday[0])+int(birthday[1]))` still returns an integer. It looks like you most likely intended to type `str((int(sumall[0])+int(sumall[1])))`, but forgot to. The reason the `str()` function fixes everything is because it converts anything in it compatible to a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
sumall = summ + sumd + sumy
```

Your `sumall` is an integer. If you want the individual characters from it, convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something like that: `(int(sumall[0])+int(sumall[1]))`

That's because `sumall` is an `int` and not a list or dict.

So, `summ + sumd` will be you're lucky number

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
sumall = summ + sumd + sumy
print "The sum of your numbers is", sumall
sumall = str(sumall) # add this line
sumln = (int(sumall[0])+int(sumall[1]))
print "Your lucky number is", sumln
```

`sumall` is a number, and you can't access its digits using the subscript notation (`sumall[0]`, `sumall[1]`). For that to work, you'll need to transform it back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for summer_69. It looks too simple to be true :)

```
def summer_69(mylist):
    ignore = False
    sum = 0
    for i in mylist:
        if i == 6:
            ignore = True
        elif not ignore:
            sum = sum + i
        elif i == 9:
            ignore = False
        
    return sum

summer_69([1,2,2,6,3,7,9,3])
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to other people if you explained a little about how it works and/or how it improves upon the existing answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement is self-explanatory.

[TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable]

You are trying to do something the computer can't do. The data type "integer" cannot be subscripted. It should be a "string" to do that.

So, convert the integer data type to a string and you will be good to go. (Go back to the lessons on data types and subscription and come back.)

Keep up all the good work!!!