# Python: Trouble sub scripting lists and accessing data in later print statement, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

This is a question that I have been tasked with, I am fairly new to Python so I am struggling a bit [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC5H4.png)

(I only need to do 8 horses)

This is my code so far:

```
horse_info = [['A',11,12],['B',17,7],['C',14,28],['D',15,10],['E',18,30],['F',13,3],['G',16,18],['H',12,23]]

max_h = int(input('Maximum height: '))
max_a = int(input('Maximum age: '))

for i in range(len(horse_info)):
    if int(max_h) <= horse_info[i[i]] and int(max_a) <= horse_info[i[i]]:
        print('yes')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/MattDaGama/Documents/Q43.py", line 7, in <module>
>     if int(max_h) <= horse_info[i[i]] and int(max_a) <= horse_info[i[i]]: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Would appreciate any help :)

EDIT:

I think I have figured out the if statement but I am not sure how to make the print statement.

```
horse_info = [['A',11,12],['B',17,7],['C',14,28],['D',15,10],['E',18,30],['F',13,3],['G',16,18],['H',12,23]]

max_h = int(input('Maximum height: '))
max_a = int(input('Maximum age: '))

for i in range(len(horse_info)
    if int(max_h) <= horse_info[i][1] and int(max_a) <= horse_info[i][2]:
        print(horse_info[i][1,2,3])
```

When I try and run the code it just doesn't print anything.

Comment: `i` is an integer... so `i[i]` makes no sense... you perhaps just mean `horse_info[i]` - although you don't need to access things by index in Python... you can loop over them directly.

Comment: Maybe `horse_info[i][1]` and `horse_info[i][2]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054854/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: I want it to go into each of the sublists and compare them

Comment: @Matthew Valetsky. The question has been asked and answered below. The answer below both answered your first and second question. I'm happy to edit at your request

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you iterate over a range, the i is an integer. The integer data type is not subscriptable (i.e. you can't do the same thing you can with a list[i] for instance to jump to the index of a list. Ints don't have indexes.

So as a starting place:

`if int(max_h) <= horse_info[i[i]] and int(max_a) <= horse_info[i[i]]:`

Should be  -

`if int(max_h) <= horse_info[i][1] and int(max_a) <= horse_info[i][2]:`

Assuming `horse_info[0][1] = 11` and `horse_info[0][2] = 12`
based on the variable declaration in the question, (i.e. `horse_info = [['A',11,12], ... ]`

You have a list of lists, and i is the index of the outer list you want to work with, and the second set of [] are the index of the value you want to work with

Comment: How would I develop the print statement

Comment: Well, you aren't printing anything because the if condition is never true. I don't know what your input values are. But ensure you actually have a horse_info that will fulfil the condition. That said ```print(horse_info[i][1,2,3])``` will error. If you want to print all the data for that list index, just do either ```print(horse_info[i])``` which will output ```['A',11,12]``` or ```print(horse_info[i][0], horse_info[i][1], horse_info[i][2])``` which will output ```A 11 12```

Comment: FYI I used 14 and 14 in my test with the edited print above and it ran fine :) If this works, please accept as answer