# Python IDLE TypeError: int object not subscriptible

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a code that makes a map (not visible), and you can move in it.

I have been working on this code for a week now.

It has a TypeError.

```
import map
def basicRealm():
     player=[0,0]#this is you
     Home=[0,0]
     Shops=[2,7]
     Park=[8,2]
     locations = [Home, Shops, Park]
     desternation=Park
     RealmSize = grid(10)
     choice = input("Move north, south, east, or west?[north/south/east/west]")
     no = int(input("Number of spaces to move: "))
     if choice=='north':
        axis=y
     elif choice=='south':
        axis=y
     elif choice=='east':
        axis==x
     elif choice=='west':
        axis=x
     else:
        pass
     nothing=''
     if choice=='south' or choice=='east':
        no = 0 - no
     else:
        pass
     you_are_here = move(no, player, axis)



  basicRealm()
```

And my map module to run it is :

```
def atDesternation(location):
    global desternation
    if desternation==location:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def atLocation(Object,locations):
    pos = position(Object)
    for i in locations:
        if pos==i:
            return i
else:
    return None

def position(Object):
     pos = (Object[0], Object[1])
     return pos

def grid(size):
     size = ListRange(0, size)
     return size

def move(spaces, thing, axis):
        here= position(thing)
        pos = here[axis] + spaces
        return pos
```

The Output is as follows:

```
Move north, south, east, or west?[north/south/east/west]north
Number of spaces to move: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\Map1.py", line 35, in <module>
   basicRealm()
File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\Map1.py", line 29, in basicRealm
   print(position(you_are_here))
File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\map.py", line 13, in position
   pos = (Object[0], Object[1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

How do I solve this error? Please help.
I am newish to Python and find it very hard to slove Errors.

Comment: sorry for all the edits, new to Stack Overflow

Comment: try reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054854/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: the issue is `you_are_here` is `int`, in `position` function you are trying to access it like a list (`pos = (Object[0], Object[1])`)

Comment: @Dave The code you posted is obviously not the code you ran. The traceback points to a line `print(position(you_are_here))` that doesn't exist in the code that you posted. However looking at your `move` function it returns an `int`, not a list. You probably meant to do something like `here[axis] += spaces` and then return `here`. Also naming one of your modules `map` is not recommended as it shadows the built-in function `map`.