# Howto convert a string to a date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

Hi guys would appreciate some help. I'm analyzng a series (a set of columns) that has a date format like this:

*'1060208'*

The first three digits represent the year where the first digit, '1' exists for comparison purposes. in the case above, the year is 2006. the 4th and 5th digit represent the month and the rest represents the day. I want to convert these dates to something like this

*106-02-08*

So that i can use *.groupby* to sort per month or year. Here is my code so far

```
    class Data:
        def convertdate(self):
            self.dates.apply(lambda x:x[0:3] + '-' + x[3:5] + '-' + x [5:7])
        return self.dates
```

when I run this, I get the error:

```
    TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Can you please tell me what went wrong? Or can you suggest some alternative way to do this? Thank you so much.

Comment: variable '1060208' is read-in as an 'int'. Check the datatype for this column. Are you creating an object for each date? I'm not clear how variable x is instantiated.

Comment: Im trying to change the format of the column dates with code above. I now change the data type to str but nothing happens it still has a format *'1060208'*

Comment: your comment is not very clear to me. More help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054854/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: all you have to do is convert the int value to string before applying the string operation. But I don't recommend you creating an object for each date. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumings that dates is a list of int, you can do:

```py
input_dates = [1060208, 1060209]
input_dates_to_str = map(lambda x: str(x), input_dates)
output = list(map(lambda x: '-'.join([x[0:3], x[3:5], x[5:]]), input_dates_to_str))
```

Anyway, when working with dates I suggest you using `datetime` package.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to your question: 1060208 is an integer, integers are not subscriptable, so you need to change it to a string.

Some other thoughts:
Where is your data? Is this all in a pandas dataframe? If so why are you writing classes to convert your data? There are better/faster ways of doing it. Like convert your intgeger date to a string, get rid of the first digit, and convert it to datetime.

What does "where 1 is put for comparison purposes" mean? It could have been recorded that way but obviously a date and a flag (I assume it is some kind of flag) should not be represented in the same field. So why don't you put that 1 in a field of its own?